# jScrollPane Unable to scroll the content on Browsers in Windows 8 touch screen laptop

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows-8, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

I am using jQuery [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) plugin in my website, It is working fine in normal PC browsers and iPad, Android tablets..

But when I open my website on Windows 8 touch screen Laptop I am unable to scroll the page with touch gestures like in iPad or Android tablet.

I tried this demo website(http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/themes/lozenge/) also, I am unable to scroll the content with touch gestures.

To scroll the page I have to go to scrollbar and drag it to left/right. Earlier with default scroll bar I am able to scroll the page with touch gestures now I can't with jScrollPane.

I am able to scroll the content(demo and my site, in windows8 Device) in **Chrome** but not in **IE and FireFox**

> Is this a known Issue? How can I fix this?
>
> Is jScrollPane supports only webkit browsers for touch gestures?
>
> If yes How can we make it to work on all browsers especially Firefox and IE?

**Update:**

As I mentioned in comment for Bruno answer, We already tried using following styles to that division.. But no luck

```
.scroll-pane{
overflow-x:scroll; 
-ms-touch-action: pan-x;    
}

and 

.scroll-pane{
overflow-x: scroll;
-ms-scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
-ms-scroll-snap-points-x: snapInterval(0%, 100%);

}
```

Answer (score 8):

Add this styles to the body tag of CSS.

```
overflow-x:scroll ; 
-ms-touch-action: pan-x;
```

It worked for me. Hope this helps you as well. Best of Luck.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, jScollPane only cares for webkit touch events (They were the only events atm) but now MS introduced the [Pointer events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673557%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that while are fairly easy to detect many devs don't do this. One other example that comes to mind is the FlexSlider plugin, that also used to only detect touchend, touchstart, etc.

If you want to make jScollPane work in Win8 you might want to modify the source and adapt it to detect MS Pointer events.

Comment: Rather than modify the jScrollPane source you could also trap the Win8 Pointer events and delegate them down to jScrollPane (assuming jScrollPane gives you the ability to do that).

Comment: @JasonL. We already tried using `-ms-touch-action: pan-x; -ms-scroll-snap-type: mandatory;-ms-scroll-snap-points-x: snapInterval(0%, 100%);` these styles via css to scroll-pane div but no luck. Ref. link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj583807%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: And Even If this works also, this will solve problem only on IE not on FireFox

Answer (score 1):

I add a MsPointerEvents (http://goo.gl/MnEIh) to a jquery.jscrollpane.js:

https://raw.github.com/karacas/jScrollPane/9fe8872f6e2438a87847e3d01b46648f06d15fc1/script/jquery.jscrollpane.js

Hope it works, sorry, but i can't tested this, because i don't have w8.